# Cannot send post request using python

Tags: python, http, post, httprequest

I'd like to send a POST request. This is my code

```
import requests 

url = "http://localhost:3000/oauth2/token"

data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 
    'client_id': 'ClientCredentialsClient', 
    'client_secret': 'Ultrasecretstuff'}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Authorization': 'auth'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print(r)
```

Instead of getting response my scripts freezes and when I stop the script I get this error

```
  File "get_token.py", line 12, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)x
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

`requests.post` has no argument headers, remove it.

Comment: `requests.post` indeed supports headers through its `**kwargs`. See: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post